# Sinch SMS get stuck after sending an SMS in an ASP.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sinch

I've been trying to integrate Sinch SMS into my ASP.net Web app using MVC 4, so far no luck, nothing works. I literally copy the code from their tutorial page on this [link](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/send-sms-sinch-net-server-side-sdk/) , however it does work when I create a c# console application and also with PHP.

To me this Nuget package ( Sinch.ServerSDK) has some problems working with ASP.NET c#, both projects are new without any other refereces to other package but only the C# console app works.

Any idea about this?.

Update 1:

this is my c# console application project and it works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sinch.ServerSdk;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sendSMS().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        private static async Task sendSMS()
        {

            var smsApi = SinchFactory.CreateApiFactory("mykey", "mysecretkey").CreateSmsApi();

            var sendSmsResponse = await smsApi.Sms("+1mynumber", "Hello world. Sinch SMS here.").Send();

        }
    }
}
```

this is my asp.net mvc web app and it doesn't work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Sinch.ServerSdk;
using Sinch.ServerSdk.Messaging;
using Sinch.WebApiClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            sendSMS().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return View();
        }

        private async Task sendSMS() {                        
            var smsApi = SinchFactory.CreateApiFactory("mykey", "mysecretkey").CreateSmsApi();
            var sendSmsResponse = await smsApi.Sms("+1mynumber", "Hello world.  Sinch SMS here.").Send(); 
        }

    }
}
```

My question is , why it works with the COnsole application and not with my Web Applicaiton.

Instead of down voting my question , let me know why, I think it will be more helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the errors that you are getting and the code you are using in your project.

Comment: @user2242618 , I don't get any errors on my web app, just stops working when sending the SMS and the thread exited., in my console application everything runs smoothly

Comment: You need to consult with the vendor on how to debug the usage of their library.  This is not a general purpose library.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, I updated my question

Comment: @codenoire, I'm trying to , but so far no answers. I just hope someone here have the Sinch SMS running with a web app

Comment: @codenoire ... what's the issue, I've been stuck with this since yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use await in MVC, you just need to set the action to Async

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
```

If you dont want to do that you can do `smsApi.Sms("+1mynumber", "Hello world.  Sinch SMS here.").Send().Result();`

Comment: geez, I can't believe I missed this, 2 days banging my head just because of this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't use "await" within an MVC application.

```
        private async Task sendSMS() {                        
            var smsApi = SinchFactory.CreateApiFactory("mykey", "mysecretkey").CreateSmsApi();
            var sendSmsResponse = await smsApi.Sms("+1mynumber", "Hello world.  Sinch SMS here.").Send(); 
        }
```

"await" means run asynchronously.  Try removing that.  Also, change the function return type to **void** instead of **async Task**

Comment: I will try this and let you know, but I need to get the messsage id in order to get the status of the SMS later on.

Comment: Who says you can't use `await`?

Comment: It's not going to behave the same as in a console app.

Comment: @codenoire, thanks man, I didn't know this, now I can't get the message id, but that's another fight I have to win :)

Comment: It is possible to run async in MVC, and recommended. see my answer below